# What will affect the value of Young's modulus?

Tags: material-science, elasticity, stress-strain

What will affect the value of Young modulus? Is it a constant for every material no matter how you change the length or area?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What factors affect the Young's modulus of elasticity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/247785/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but only under certain conditions like small stresses and strains and within the elastic limits of the material. Real world materials are isotropic meaning that they will have different characteristics in different orientations. Youngs Modulus is also a derivation from Hookes law, which most materials will obey under small stresses and strains, but will often become non elastic under big stresses or strains, including affects like atomic slippage and breaking. Temperature can change the characteristics of a material, and volume of the material can introduce physical defects like cracking that can break the elastic behavior too. Youngs Modulus is the ratio between stess and strain for elastic materials only.

Comment: Real world materials are _sometimes_ isotopic. Any good mechanical engineer will be able to tell you the impacts on mechanical properties of, say, a rolling mill (which leaves the material in an anisotropic strain state).